# How to customize Inno Setup WizardForm scrollbar

Tags: windows-installer, scrollbar, inno-setup

I am currently working on a custom installer made by Inno Setup. I found some ways to customize the UI of most of the WizardForm. Yet I didn't see any way to customize the scrollbar, I wonder if anyone knows how to change the style of the scrollbar?

Comment: Not with the standard Inno Setup. Maybe with some Inno Setup clone or a DLL.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to accomplish? If you can elaborate someone might be able to suggest an alternative that would be easier (or at least possible).

Comment: My issue was that there's a license page during the installation process. I have already customized the inno setup iss file and with the WizardForm. But I wasn't able to change the style for that scrollbar of the license page. So that was my major problem.